# Wordpress menu cut off at a specific point, Chrome for Android browser appears to refuse to render it

Tags: android, css, wordpress

I have a strange browser-specific rendering issue that occurs only on Chrome for Android. (incognito and none-incognito)

You can view a live sample of this issue here: https://www.tealsprairie.com/
1. Open the website above on an Android device with Chrome app
2. Tap on hamburger menu on top-right corner.
3. Tap on the mini arrow icon beside PERSONALIZED GIFTS to expand the menu.
4. Scroll down till you see an empty space after the "Home" sub category.

Screenshot of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYQu2.jpg

This empty space doesn't make sense because the HTML elements are there. You can view it by using Chrome Dev Tool's Remote Devices feature and inspecting the elements on your PC.
Elements: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsW43.jpg

Chrome app version **77.0.3865.92**
Also tested on Chrome Beta app version **78.0.3904.43**

Tested on Firefox android, Chrome desktop, Firefox desktop, Chrome iOS. None of these browsers are affected.

Next, I gave the entire `li` element a `position: fixed;` and a `z-index` of 99999 to rule out any z-index issues. Did not work. It still gets cut off at the same specific spot.

I then gave the parent `ul` element a `overflow: scroll;` , and it made the `ul` scrollable and hence I am now able to see the "hidden" elements by scrolling the `ul`. But then the whole `ul` now gets cut off at the point where the menu items were hidden in the first place!
screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXWiH.jpg

Tried adding new menu items, rearranging the menus in Wordpress etc. It gets cut off at the exact same point in all scenarios.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Consider reporting on https://cbug.com if it's not there already.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm thanks for the comment, but I can't seem to access the site you mentioned. Are you referring to chromium bug tracker ?

Comment: Yep, https://crbug.com, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm , I have made a report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012195